# Probability of winning more than half of the games with stronger opponent

Tags: probability

I'm training probability and i can't really figure out how to get the right answer.

We have to play $2N$ matches (where $N$ is natural number) with stronger opponent. It is: probability p of winning single match is less than $\dfrac12$. 
Question is: How to choose $N$ such that we have greatest probability of winning more than half matches. 
I figured out $N$ has to be dependent on $p$ but i can't really solve it.

I'd really appreciate some help or tips on this! Cheers

Comment: What happens when $N$ becomes large, do you think we will be able to go against the odds often and win $N$ games? Same question applies for the case when $N$ is small, can we more easily, or less easily win $N$ games?

Comment: @Ritz My intuition was that answer will always be some low $N$. 
Cause if $N=1$ then we want need to win 2 matches, so probability of that is $p^2$ 
if $N=2$ then we need to win 3 matches or 4 matches. 
if $N=3$ then we need to win 4,5 or 6 matches. 
To me it seemed like random variable of number of won matches with binomial distribution, but i was stuck here... I'd appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of winning a single match is $p < 1/2$. The probability of winning $k$ games out of a total of $2N$ games played, is

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\text{win }k \text{ games}) = \binom{2N}{k} (1-p)^{2N-k} p^k.
\end{align}

We are interested in the probability of winning more than half the matches, i.e. $N+1$ or more. This is given by

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\text{win more than half the games}) &= \sum_{k = N+1}^{2N} \mathbb{P}(\text{win }k \text{ games}) \\
&= \sum_{k = N+1}^{2N} \binom{2N}{k} (1-p)^{2N-k} p^k \\
&= 1 - \sum_{k = 0}^N \binom{2N}{k} (1-p)^{2N-k} p^k.
\end{align}

This probability has a maximum as a function of $N$. For example, when $p = 0.4$ we obtain the maximum probability at $N = 2$ or $N = 3$ (both have equal probability), and for $p = 0.2$ we get $N = 1$.

I hope someone else can help you with the explicit characterization of the number of games $N$ as a function of $p$ that gives you maximum probability of winning more than half the games. So this is a not a complete answer to your question.

Comment: Yeah, i was stuck there, this problem seems a little bit hard.